# Как сделать выборку из MySQL TIMESTAMP по time()?

Tags: php, mysql

В базе есть поле **testtime** в формате TIMESTAMP, мне надо получить все записи, например, за последний час.
Как реализовать нечто подобное:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE testtime>'".(time()-3600)."'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> мне надо получить все записи, например, за последний час

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE testtime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
-- AND testtime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Да, получается только так. Хорошо, что точность не нужна особо. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Vadim Не понял - а что не так с точностью-то?

Comment: Akina, нормально все, затупил немного

Answer (score 1):

Тип timestamp в MySQL это дата. То есть это не просто количество секунд, это дата, которая хранится как количество секунд. Это означает, что арифметика с секундами не пройдёт.

Посмотрите

```sql
select
    current_timestamp - 3600,
    unix_timestamp() - 3600;
```

Поэтому либо используйте [функции для работы с датой](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html), либо преобразуйте timestamp в количество секунд.

Comment: *Тип timestamp в MySQL это дата. То есть это не просто количество секунд, это дата, которая хранится как количество секунд.* В общем случае это ошибочная интерпретация. Особенно с учётом того, что при любых операциях (кроме прямого сравнения двух значений типа TIMESTAMP) операнд сначала будет приведёт к DATETIME.

Comment: @Akina ну я это и пытался сказать. Под датой имею ввиду что-то, что ведёт себя как datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE testtime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-3600
```

Comment: Что-то у меня глюк какой-то. Есть одна свежая сегодняшняя запись и несколько прошлогодних. Если делаю выборку, например, за 25 часов, все нормально, если 25ч+1 секунда, то все записи выдает. Время примерное, порог срабатывания глюка растет с каждой секундой. Это можно увидеть в режиме реального времени, просто рефреша страницу.

Comment: А вы проверяли, что это работает? Я для таких случаев завёл себе проект с докер-композом -- поднял тестовую базку, сделал несколько запросов и потом отвечаю. Очень помогает избежать опечаток и других ошибок. И в работе помогает, когда хочется проверить какие-нибудь идеи. Рекомендую.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Зачем так сложно? есть же https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 и иные online fiddle